# how do i merge 2d lists with the same named object and add there values together in a new list?

Tags: python, list

i would like to know how to combine data in multiple lists, i have combined them in a way so that they all congregate in the same [] but there are objects with the same name and different values that i want to combine the values and only have one object representing it. basically how do i combine the two "bananas" objects ?
[image]

i havent tried anything that has worked because i cant find anything specifically related to my issue, i understand that its simple i just cannot find a specific enough answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: FYI, the `sort()` method takes a `reverse=True` option, you don't need to call `merge.reverse()` afterward.

Comment: Convert the first list to a dictionary. Then loop over the other lists, either creating a new dictionary element or combining with the existing key as necessary.

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: You could use `defaultdict`, for instance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code AS TEXT. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Or simply `if key in dictionary: ... else: ...`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I already said that in the first comment.

Comment: could you show me how to do that if possible ?

Comment: @Barmar Sure, but I added a link to the page in the [SO Community FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) which I feel is a bit more informative.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp OK. I've added that to my canned comment, I'll ue it in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
fruit = [['apple', 5], ['pears', 10], ['bananas', 12]]
items = [['cars', 3], ['sheets', 5], ['bananas', 8]]
colors = [['blue', 3], ['black', 5], ['orange', 8]]
merge = fruit + items + colors
result = set(
    (item, sum(quantity for label, quantity in merge if label == item))
    for item, _ in merge
)
result
```

Output

```
{('apple', 5),
 ('bananas', 20),
 ('black', 5),
 ('blue', 3),
 ('cars', 3),
 ('orange', 8),
 ('pears', 10),
 ('sheets', 5)}
```